# collapsing rows based on two other colums in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

In my thesis I have a dataframe with variables `year`, `agegroup`, `count`.
For each `year` I want to collapse `agegroups` '0-4', '5-9' and '10-14' into '0-14', summing `count`.

I want this:

```
  year agegroup count
1 1990      0-4     1
2 1990      5-9     1
3 1990    10-14     1
4 1990    15-19     7
5 1991      0-4     1
6 1991      5-9     3
7 1991    10-14     1
8 1991    15-19     7
```

to become this:

```
  year agegroup count
1 1990     0-14     3
2 1990    15-19     7
3 1991     0-14     5
4 1991    15-19     7
```

I can't figure out how to do this neatly, would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$agegroup2=gsub("0-4|5-9|10-14","0-14",df$agegroup)

aggregate(count~year+agegroup2,df,sum)

  year agegroup2 count
1 1990      0-14     3
2 1991      0-14     5
3 1990     15-19     7
4 1991     15-19     7
```